# If a creature with Multiattack is affected by Haste, can it make two Multiattacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, actions, multiattack

It's a fairly straightforward question.

A creature has a *Multiattack* option, and it also can cast the *Haste* spell. **While under the effect of *Haste*, can it use the second Action to take another *Multiattack* Action?**

My main concern is the clause of the *Haste* spell that limits the number of attacks made from taking the *Attack* Action. This is a different Action, though.

Then there is the concern of being able to use *Multiattack* at all, because *Haste* says what kinds of Actions you can take.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As you have mentioned, the spell *haste* tells you exactly what you may do with the extra action granted by it. The relevant portion is:

> Th[e extra] action [from *haste*] can be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

As the Multiattack action is a separate type of action (see the listing on page 11 of the Monster Manual, noting it is separated from ordinary ranged or weapon attacks), you cannot use it via the extra action granted by *haste*.

Comment: Jeremy Crawford has several tweets that support this interpretation [here is one](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/606188197098315776)