# Can a hasted monster make the additional attack from the Haste spell along with their Multiattack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, attack, multiattack

If a spellcaster casts *haste* on a monster with Multiattack, does he/she get to make the extra attack (one weapon attack only) from *haste* after his/her Multiattack?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes, a hasted monster can Attack and Multiattack in the same turn

*Haste* says:

> It gains an additional action on each of its turns. That action can be
> used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash,
> Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

Multiattack is a special action that monsters can take, it is listed in the Monster Manual (p. 11) under the Actions section.

If a monster takes the Multiattack action, then they can still use the *haste* action for any of the actions allowed by it, including to attack. In this way the monster could Multiattack and Attack in the same turn while hasted.

It is worth noting that the order in which you take these actions is up to you so you may take the extra Attack action from *haste* before the Multiattack, for example.

#### Note: a hasted monster cannot Multiattack twice using the haste action

A related question to the one you seem to have asked (but included for completeness in case you were curious) is if one can use the extra action granted by *haste* to take another Multiattack action. To which the answer is no.

Multiattack is a special action that monsters can take, but it is not any of the actions listed in *haste*.

[Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/606188197098315776) has clarified that:

> Multiattack and Attack are different actions.

Attack is listed in *haste* as an acceptable action, but Multiattack is not.

Therefore, a monster cannot use the additional action granted by haste to take another Multiattack.

See this question for more on that aspect: [If a creature with Multiattack is affected by Haste, can it make two Multiattacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86327/if-a-creature-with-multiattack-is-affected-by-haste-can-it-make-two-multiattack)