# Does the Echo Knight fighter's Unleash Incarnation feature add another attack to the additional Attack action from the Haste spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, fighter, echo-knight

The [Echo Knight fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#EchoKnight)'s [Unleash Incarnation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#UnleashIncarnation-1810361) feature says (EGtW, p. 183):

> Whenever you take the Attack action, you can make one additional melee attack from the echo’s position.

If the [*haste*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) spell is cast on an Echo Knight, can they use their additional Attack action from *haste* to trigger an Unleash Incarnation attack?

The wording on the feature makes me think it's additive ("additional melee attack") and triggers after the Attack action, which is not limited by the number of attacks you can do in an action.

If this works, does it mean a *haste*d Echo Knight can make an additional 3 attacks, for a total of 8 attacks in 1 turn at 5th level?
(Attack action (2 attacks) + UI + *haste*d Attack action (1 attack) + UI + Action Surge Attack action (2 attacks) + UI)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Related: [Does Extra Attack stack with Haste?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100601/does-extra-attack-stack-with-haste), [Haste spell: what does “one weapon attack only” mean?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77612/haste-spell-what-does-one-weapon-attack-only-mean), [Can a hasted monster make the additional attack from the Haste spell along with their Multiattack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117105/can-a-hasted-monster-make-the-additional-attack-from-the-haste-spell-along-with)

Answer (score 15):

## Unleash Incarnation cannot exceed *haste*'s limit

*Haste* states that the target

> gains an additional action on each of its turns. That action can be used only to take the Attack (**one weapon attack only**), Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

*Haste* does **not** set a baseline of one attack to which you can add more. Rather, ***haste* sets a limit on the number of weapon attacks you can make with its Attack action**. Hence, you cannot make both the normal attack and the Unleash Incarnation attack when you take the *haste*'s Attack action, because that would exceed the limit of one weapon attack.

Moreover, the Unleash Incarnation attack is **not** some attack that occurs after the Attack action, nor is it separate from that Attack action. Rather, **the Unleash Incarnation attack is part of the Attack action**, so it's subject to the limits that *haste* imposes on the Attack action.

The above is the exact same reason why Extra Attack also can't exceed *haste*'s limit. As a matter of fact, the relevant wording of Unleash Incarnation and Extra Attack are the same:

> **Whenever you take the Attack action**, you can make one additional melee attack from the echo's position.

and

> you can attack twice, instead of once, **whenever you take the Attack action** on your turn.

Comment: After review, I think I've come to support this answer over my own.

Comment: Can you support this claim: "Unleash Incarnation attack is part of the Attack action,"? The Ranger's Stalker's Flurry feature explicitly states this: "Once on each of your turns when you miss with a weapon attack, you can make another weapon attack as part of the same action." [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125161) seems to disagree as well

Comment: Oh I see, you're using Extra Attack as supporting evidence. Not sure where I stand now XD

Answer (score 4):

#### Unleash Incarnation can be used with *haste*

The *haste* spell notably limits *its own Attack action* to being one weapon attack only; however, Unleash Incarnation is *not* part of the Attack action. We can compare it to the Gloom Stalker Ranger's Stalker's Flurry feature (emphasis mine):

> [...] Whenever you take the Attack action, you can make one additional melee attack from the echo's position. [...]

> [...] Once on each of your turns when you miss with a weapon attack, you can make another weapon attack **as part of the same action.**

As we can see, when a feature adds an attack directly *to* the Attack action, it states this directly. Therefore, Unleash Incarnation is *not* part of the Attack action and is *not* limited by *haste's* "one weapon attack only" clause.

---

There is also a similar question about *haste* and Horde Breaker (I will quote [its highest-scoring answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/125163)):

- [Does the Horde Breaker feature work on the attack granted by Haste?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125161)

> Horde Breaker says:
>
> > Once on each of your turns when you make a weapon attack, you can make another attack with the same weapon against a different creature...
>
> Since haste grants the ability to make one weapon attack as part of an Attack action, it will definitely be a valid trigger for the Horde Breaker ability.
>
> This will work even though haste specifies that the Attack action can be used to take only one weapon attack, because the Horde Breaker attack is not made as part of that Attack action. It just happens to be triggered by that action, so it does not violate that stipulation.

Similarly then, Unleash Incarnation is *not* part of the Attack action and can be used with *haste*.

Horde Breaker and Unleash Incarnation use very similar wording and I would therefore treat them the same, that is, that they *both* can "get around" the restriction from *haste*.

> [...] Whenever you take the Attack action, you can make one additional [...] attack [...]

> [...] When you make a weapon attack, you can make another attack [...]

Answer (score -2):

I don’t even think haste can be cast on the echo knight, haste must be cast on a willing CREATURE. Echo knight is an OBJECT.

Comment: This is not an answer. Once you gain sufficient reputation you can comment on questions and answers.